# Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Tags: angularjs, http, oauth, cors

I implemented token based oauth login using angular js, and after I login to any of the providers, I get the above error on every get request I make thereafter to a third party API(tmdb) service using `$http`.

After I logout however, everything starts working back as normal. I'm not setting, modifying anything.. why is this happening?

**Things I tried**

`$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = undefined ;`

```
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'];
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = undefined ;
```

**Request Headers after I login to any oauth:**

```
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-RateLimit-Limit:40
X-RateLimit-Remaining:28
X-RateLimit-Reset:1452454281
Request Headers
view parsed
OPTIONS /3/movie/popular?api_key=de75f0397cd2a7184400275e3331f039 HTTP/1.1
Host: api.themoviedb.org
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://popcorn-movies.dev:3001
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2612.0 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, authorization
Accept: */*
Referer: http://popcorn-movies.dev:3001/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,hi;q=0.6
```

Comment: The response headers for your `OPTIONS` request to https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=de75f0397cd2a7184400275e3331f039 needs to include the response header `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization` but it seems like you are not getting the header in the response. So to get more help from others here, you probably want to [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34709954/edit) and add the response headers to it.